# Intermittent Water Flow And Potentially Busted Pipe

Tags: plumbing, well-pump, well

We have a well that has been causing us some trouble. The pressure gauge/pressure switch assembly on our water tank is older and rusted due to the high calcium/mineral content in our water here.

(1.)We have an outdoor spigot that I noticed had a puddle of water rising from the ground around it while I was using it. This is my main concern because the only thing that makes sense is a busted pipe. Is there anyway of troubleshooting this without digging?

(2.) Also, the water pressure inside our house has always been poor, which is likely due to a bad seal(pressure gauge) or obstruction in the pipe. Within the last couple of days though, suddenly it will cut off for at least a minute before flowing again with higher than normal pressure. I don't know if it's relevant, but the water pressure in our shower/bath is much higher than any other faucet in our home. I did come across an article that indicated it could be a faulty pressure switch that is causing the intermittent flow of water.

Comment: It is probably the pressure switch but the pressure tank can add to the problem if not charged with air.

Comment: Took two long to edit,, If you run water and the pump kicks on with no delay you will need to charge the tank. If your outside spigot only leaks when in use this would be unusual unless it is turned off closer to the house. Turn it off at the point where the hose is connected and leave pressure in the line, if it keeps bubbling you will need to dig it up. Old galvanized pipe with high mineral content builds up inside the pipe and this may be the cause for low flow. If you have good pressure that drops off quickly, it can be the pressure tank, low pressure in some but not all can be bad pipes.